# Question for the probability of not being chosen

Tags: probability

Suppose there are three sets, $A$, $B$ and $C$. Set $A$ has $30$ elements, Set $B$ has $14$ elements and Set $C$ has $1$ element. The three sets are then put in a singular set where they are picked randomly. What is the probabilility that, after $44$ tries, that $A$ will be the only remaining element left? What about $B$?

For $C$, the answer is pretty easy. The probability of not being chosen is $44/45$. When one that is not $C$ is picked, it becomes $43/44$. It becomes a telescoping series which comes down to $1/45$. For the others, I'm not so sure about.

Comment: Is choosing with or without replacement? In other words, does an element return to the mixed set after chosing?

Comment: Perhaps it wouldn't be a bad idea to think of the problem like this: When put together, the elements are
$$
A_1, ~ A_2, ~A_3 , \ldots, A_{30}, ~B_{31}, ~ B_{32}, \ldots, ~ B_{44}, ~C_{45}
$$
Now, what is the probability that $A_1$ is not chosen?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

All $45$ elements have *equal probability* to become the unique one that is not picked and $30$ of them are members of set $A$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming by $A$ being left you mean that after the elimination, the element that remains came from $A$. Now what I do instead is to flip the problem. Rather than picking elements to leave, I pick elements that will stay. So the problem above is analogous to saying that if I picked an element to stay, what is the probability that it is from set A?

That would obviously be $\frac{n(A)}{n(A) + n(B) + n(C)} = \frac{30}{45} = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: It's for case picking without replacement, right?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Indeed without replacement. It is not explicitly stated in the question but becomes clear when your read about the way the OP handled set $C$.

Comment: So the answer is right, no?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Else I would not have upvoted your answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is redundant... and the best solution is the one of @dhrab (+1), but without doing any brainstorming, using the hypergeometric law, the answer is

$$\frac{\binom{30}{29}\binom{14}{14}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{45}{44}}=\frac{\binom{30}{1}}{\binom{45}{1}}=\frac{30}{45}$$